# Unable to start Zookeeper on windows

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

Hello I am trying to use SolrCloud on different machine. for that I have refereed these documents: [here](https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/203187153-Install-and-start-Zookeeper-server-on-Windows) & [here](http://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/susheelk/2015/08/03/solrcloud-2-nodes-solr-1-node-zk-setup/)

But I am facing an issue: **Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain in windows**

Here is a screenshot: [image]

Can you please help how to Start Zookeeper server on windows.

Please note I have tried to run with command **zkServer** as well without start word.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have zookeeper-3.*.*.jar in your classpath.

Its generally placed in zookeeper/dist-maven/

You can add up that location too in ur zkServer.cmd

Comment: classpath means in bin folder? I do not have any dist-maven folder. In which parameter I have to configure location of jar file?

Comment: Assuming you have call %JAVA% "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=%ZOO_LOG_DIR%" "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=%ZOO_LOG4J_PROP%" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" %ZOOMAIN% "%ZOOCFG%" %* in your zkServer.cmd


Use 
SET CLASSPATH=%~dp0..\build\classes;%~dp0..\build\lib\*;%CLASSPATH%;<Path to your jar> in zkEnv.cmd